# Is the function Convex

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $A$ is a $n\times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix and $1<p<\infty$. Is the map $T:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ given by $T(x)=|Ax\cdot x|^\frac{p}{2}$ convex?

Where $|\cdot|$ is the usual inner product.

As I see for $p=2$, it is convex but I can't do for the general case.

Comment: You could transform it to |A^{1/2}x|^p. Without the p this is a norm. Then use the triangle inequality a bit and I am sure the result will follow, no?

Comment: How?  I don't understand. Please write explicitly.

Comment: Well, you know that $Ax \cdot x = A^{1/2}x \cdot A^{1/2}x$ for two positive matrices $A^{\frac{1}{2}}$, right? Then $|Ax \cdot x|^{\frac{1}{2}} = \|A^{\frac{1}{2}}x\|$ and $\|A^{\frac{1}{2}}x\|$ is a norm. A norm is convex. Combining it with the function $x \mapsto x^p$ for $p>0$ does not destroy the convexity. But the last part you simply need to calculate.

Comment: the function $x\mapsto x^p$ is convex for $p>1$ but not a problem its given already $p>1$

Comment: You are right, $p>1$ is what I meant to say instead of $p>0$. $0<p<1$ would actually not work.

Answer (score 1):

For $p \geq 2$, $T(x)$ is convex.

Notice that $T(x) = (x^\top A x)^{p/2}$ is the composition of $f(x) = x^\top A x$ and $g(t) = \max\{0, t^{p/2}\}$. For $p \geq 2$, $g$ is a nondecreasing function on $\mathbb{R}_+$ and also convex as the pointwise maximum of two convex functions. Additionally, $f$ is convex as a positive-definite quadratic form, and $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n, f(x) \geq 0$. Then, we obtain:

$$
f(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda) y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1 - \lambda) f(y) \Rightarrow  \\
\underbrace{g(f(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda) y))}_{T(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y)} \overset{g \uparrow}{\leq} g(\lambda f(x) + (1 - \lambda) f(y))
\overset{g \text{ convex}}{\leq} \underbrace{\lambda g(f(x))}_{\lambda T(x)} + \underbrace{(1 - \lambda) g(f(y))}_{(1 - \lambda) T(y)}
$$
which is the defining inequality for convexity of a function.

Comment: Well. What about $1<p<2$?

Comment: Can I take f(x)=(Ax.x)^{1/2}? If so then its true for any p>1.